# rte_eth_tx_burst can not send packet out

Tags: dpdk

A dpdk application which generate a few arp request packets and call rte_eth_tx_burst to send them out, some packets are not received by peer NIC port(this can be confirmed by using wireshark to capture the packets from the peer NIC), `dpdk-proc-info` shows no error count. **But before call rte_eth_tx_burst let the app sleep 10s, it can send all the packets.**

example codes:

```
main(){
  port_init();
  sleep(10);
  gen_pkt(mbuf);
  rte_eth_tx_burst(mbuf);
}
```

System setup: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, dpdk-stable-20.11.3, I350 Gigabit Network Connection 1521, igb_uio driver

```
root@k8s-node:/home/dpdk-stable-20.11.3/build/app# ./dpdk-proc-info -- --xstats
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
###### NIC extended statistics for port 0  #########
####################################################
rx_good_packets: 10
tx_good_packets: 32
rx_good_bytes: 1203
tx_good_bytes: 1920
rx_missed_errors: 0
rx_errors: 0
tx_errors: 0
rx_mbuf_allocation_errors: 0
rx_q0_packets: 0
rx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_q0_errors: 0
tx_q0_packets: 0
tx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_crc_errors: 0
rx_align_errors: 0
rx_symbol_errors: 0
rx_missed_packets: 0
tx_single_collision_packets: 0
tx_multiple_collision_packets: 0
tx_excessive_collision_packets: 0
tx_late_collisions: 0
tx_total_collisions: 0
tx_deferred_packets: 0
tx_no_carrier_sense_packets: 0
rx_carrier_ext_errors: 0
rx_length_errors: 0
rx_xon_packets: 0
tx_xon_packets: 0
rx_xoff_packets: 0
tx_xoff_packets: 0
rx_flow_control_unsupported_packets: 0
rx_size_64_packets: 4
rx_size_65_to_127_packets: 3
rx_size_128_to_255_packets: 3
rx_size_256_to_511_packets: 0
rx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 0
rx_size_1024_to_max_packets: 0
rx_broadcast_packets: 0
rx_multicast_packets: 10
rx_undersize_errors: 0
rx_fragment_errors: 0
rx_oversize_errors: 0
rx_jabber_errors: 0
rx_management_packets: 0
rx_management_dropped: 0
tx_management_packets: 0
rx_total_packets: 10
tx_total_packets: 32
rx_total_bytes: 1203
tx_total_bytes: 1920
tx_size_64_packets: 32
tx_size_65_to_127_packets: 0
tx_size_128_to_255_packets: 0
tx_size_256_to_511_packets: 0
tx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 0
tx_size_1023_to_max_packets: 0
tx_multicast_packets: 0
tx_broadcast_packets: 32
tx_tso_packets: 0
tx_tso_errors: 0
rx_sent_to_host_packets: 0
tx_sent_by_host_packets: 0
rx_code_violation_packets: 0
interrupt_assert_count: 0
####################################################

root@k8s-node:/home/dpdk-stable-20.11.3/build/app# ./dpdk-proc-info -- --stats
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created

  ######################## NIC statistics for port 0  ########################
  RX-packets: 5           RX-errors:  0           RX-bytes:  785       
  RX-nombuf:  0         
  TX-packets: 32          TX-errors:  0           TX-bytes:  1920      

  Stats reg  0 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  1 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  2 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  3 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  4 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  5 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  6 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  7 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  8 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  9 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 10 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 11 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 12 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 13 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 14 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 15 RX-packets: 0           RX-errors: 0           RX-bytes: 0         

  Stats reg  0 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  1 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  2 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  3 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  4 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  5 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  6 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  7 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  8 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg  9 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 10 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 11 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 12 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 13 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 14 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  Stats reg 15 TX-packets: 0           TX-bytes: 0         
  ############################################################################
```

**update:**
Thanks for your response, I modified the codes:

```
main(){
  uint32_t port_mask = 0x1;
  port_init();
  check_all_ports_link_status(port_mask);
  gen_pkt(mbuf);
  rte_eth_tx_burst(mbuf);
}
```

got the print logs:

```
Checking link status...............................
done
Port0 Link Up. Speed 1000 Mbps - full-duplex
```

I think the NIC should have initallized completely, but the peer NIC port still missed a lot of packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most working cases the Physical NIC is enumerated for Duplex (full/half), speed (1, 10, 25, 40, 50, 100, 200) and negotiated for (auto/disable) within 1 second. Anything exceeding 2 or 3 seconds is the sign of connected machine or switch not able to negotiated with Duplex, speed or auto-negotiation. Hence the recommendation is

1. update the driver, firmware on both sides if the interfaces are NIC
2. Test out the different connection cable as link-sense might not be reaching properly
3. in case of hub or switch try fixing speed and auto-negotiation.
4. I do not recommend changing from FULL duplex to Half duplex (as it could be cable or SFI issue).

As temporary work around for the time being you can use [rte_eth_link_get](http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html) which also states it might need `It might need to wait up to 9 seconds`.

Note: easy way to test if it is cable issue is running DPDK on both ends to check time required for link to be up.

Modified Code Snippet:

```
main(){
  port_init();
  
  RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(portid) {
   struct rte_eth_link link;
   memset(&link, 0, sizeof(link));

   do {
        retval = rte_eth_link_get_nowait(port, &link);
        if (retval < 0) {
            printf("Failed link get (port %u): %s\n",
                port, rte_strerror(-retval));
            return retval;
        } else if (link.link_status)
            break;
        printf("Waiting for Link up on port %"PRIu16"\n", port);
        sleep(1);
    } while (!link.link_status);
  }

  gen_pkt(mbuf);
  rte_eth_tx_burst(mbuf);
}
```

or

```
main(){
  port_init();
  
  RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(portid) {
   struct rte_eth_link link;
   memset(&link, 0, sizeof(link));
   ret = rte_eth_link_get(portid, &link);
   if (ret < 0) {
            printf("Port %u link get failed: err=%d\n", portid, ret);
            continue;
    }

  gen_pkt(mbuf);
  rte_eth_tx_burst(mbuf);
}
```

Comment: please make a look at the update , thanks

Comment: @happy as per the update stated you are having 1Gbps NIC which looses packet. What is your application running on other NIC (is it DPDK, raw socket, pdump, tcpdump).  Please note your orginal question is `rte_eth_tx_burst can not send packet out` and `not  peer NIC port still missed a lot of packets.`. Maybe there is something missing in the orignal question

Comment: @happy also noticed the answer is unaccepted, small update as mentioned in the previous comment answer shared is for `rte_eth_tx_burst can not send packet out` and not for updated second question `peer NIC port still missed a lot of packets`. Please share peer nic details and application details and how is started to better help you

Comment: thanks for your help. "peer NIC port still missed a lot of packets" means : after I call `check_all_ports_link_status(port_mask)` API before `rte_eth_tx_burst`, the peer NIC still can not receive packets unless add `sleep(10)` before calling `rte_eth_tx_burst`

Comment: @happy you still have not sahred what is your application on peer side. you have not mentioned whether you are checkign the link status as shared in the code snippet. My recommendation is live debug.

Comment: the tcpdump was used to capture the peer NIC and the NIC link status is up ,I accepted your recommendation, could you login the skype, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's no surprise that packets can't be sent until the physical link goes up. That takes some time, and one can use `rte_eth_link_get()` [API](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#a56200b0c25f3ecab5abe9bd2b647c215) to automate waiting.

Comment: please make a look at the update , thanks